# Flutter - How to create a wiggly animation?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, border

I am new to flutter and I am trying to create something like this:

[image]

It doesn't have to be exactly like this but something similar and more importantly, easy to implement, is what I am looking for.

I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Mentally ignore the rotation. The thin circle is doing the same thing as the thick circle with different offset/timing. The circle is basically a bezier circle with 8 control points.  The control points animate between two positions: normal and "inner" which creates the bumps. Flutter has a ClipPath and CustomClipper that supports bezier shapes. You can have a red Container() with your custom clipper that animates the control points between two positions over time/frames. Duplicate it with a thinner clip and put the two circles in a Stack(). Next add rotation with RotationTransition().

Comment: The center is just a rounded square (Container()) with a ScaleTransition() - slowly getting larger. It would be on the top of your Stack(). It has a BoxShadow() that is red.

Comment: This looks like the right way, but it's just too tough to implement. Getting those bezier curves looks very very very difficult.

Comment: If you just want to create a keyframe-animated element some answers are recommending Lottie. I haven't used Lottie but an alternative I have used is Rive.app which has it's own online editor. It's the same price as After Effects (what Lottie uses to create Animation.) Just something else to check out if you're looking to go that route for your animation.

Comment: I know rive, and I tried to do it in rive, but not ny cup of tea. I am not a designer and the learning curve to achieve something like this will be too big...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use
[blobs](https://pub.dev/packages/blobs)

Create an animated blob like this

```
Blob.animatedRandom(
 size:200,
 edgesCount:5,
 minGrowth:4,
 duration:  Duration(milliseconds:500),
 styles:  BlobStyles(
 color:  Colors.red,
 fillType:  BlobFillType.stroke,
 strokeWidth:3,
 ),
),
```

Wrap it with an animated container and rotate it in loops. Adjust values as required. You can also use it in a stack to achieve results as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display only animation that is not depend or control by any flutter variable then [lottie](https://lottiefiles.com/) is easiest way to do it, it is as simple as display an image.

select animation from lotties [free market](https://lottiefiles.com/search?q=circle&category=animations&animations-page=1),
then  import package `lottie` from pub.dev, [link](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie)

and then use as you display an image like below,

```
// Load a Lottie file from your assets
Lottie.asset('assets/LottieLogo1.json'),

// Load a Lottie file from a remote url
Lottie.network('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xvrh/lottie-flutter/master/example/assets/Mobilo/A.json'),

// Load an animation and its images from a zip file
Lottie.asset('assets/lottiefiles/angel.zip'),
```

here's [something](https://lottiefiles.com/74499-circle) i found that is may suitable for your need.

Comment: Color is important

Comment: article on how to update color, https://lottiefiles.com/blog/updates/introducing-the-lottie-editor

Answer (score 1):

For the Animation like below, you can implement with https://lottiefiles.com
as @Ruchit advised. This is the best and way more time saving option available.

I have updated some with your color scheme

From pub.dev [Lottie package](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) you can implement to your Application

NOTE: You can check with your designer if available and get the json file

[image: Here is the output little similar to yours]
[image: Here is the output little similar to yours]